# Wicket: Define Application wide variable

Tags: java, session, wicket

I wanted to make a little "log" on what the user is doing. I have different panels and all of these have Ajax functions such as "onclick", "onevent" and "onchange". What I planned was to define an Application wide ArrayList of Strings to log all the things.
I wrote following into **WicketApplication.java**

```
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {

private List<String> log = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage() {
    //code
}

@Override
public void init() {
    //code
}

public List<String> getLog() {
    return log;
}

public void setLog(List<String> log) {
    this.log = log;
}}
```

Then in one of my panels:

```
public class Foo extends Panel{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private WicketApplication wapp = (WicketApplication) Application.get();

public Foo(String id){
    super(id);
}

public void bar(){
    List<String> protocol = wapp.getLog();
    protocol.add(foo.getBarName() + " has been added to " + selectedKontakt.getObject().getName());
    wapp.setLog(protocol);
}
}
```

In a next panel I tried to create a new reference to WicketApplication. But it seems not to be the same. 
Now I have these questions:

- Isn't WicketApplication unique and therefore usable for this kind of manipulation?
- Do I have to take a session for this?
- Can I even parse Applcation to WebApplication? Because I have this error in the console

> wapp <----- field that is causing the problem

Is there any other way to create an Application wide variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal way of use is (static) method. Its typical, don't be afraid.

```
MyApllication m = MyApllication.get();
```

So is genrally easy in every wicket object.
Usually "statically overrided" to return correct type, (and can give additional control).

```
public static MyApllication getMyApplication() {
        return (MyApllication) get();
    }
```

or

```
 public static MyApllication get() {
        return (MyApllication ) WebApplication.get();
    }
```

When this static method returns correct type, Your problem is resolved.

Analyse how is build `AuthenticatedWebApplication` over `WebApplication` (or `WebApplication` over `Application`) , its from Wicket team and seems be canonical

BTW I You will have idea access / execute actions dependent on user / session similar idea exist : `WebSession` override in `MySession`

Comment: Thank you, the WebSession was the solution. This [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=76385) helped.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are doing it wrong (on multiple levels).

Firstly: if you want to log, use a Logging framework. E.g. [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/), preferably accessed through [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/)

Secondly: if you don't want to use a log framework, create a log service (a dedicated object, not the Wicket Application), use Dependency Injection to inject the log service into all components where you need it. Wicket Supports both [Spring](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Spring) and [Guice](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/guice)

Third: Static access to the `WebApplication` as suggested by the accepted answer sounds like a very bad idea (but it is apparently suggested by Wicket, to be fair).

Comment: Thank you for the input. I know that it is not the final solution. I intended to get something simple to work first, to see how it works. I will switch to _Log4J_

Comment: I've chosen SLF4J due to an import error I get with Log4J, no idea why, but SLF4J works just as good. Thank you.

Comment: 1. by first contact Wicket+injecting has point precise must understand (it was my problem - You write ok): injection works in COMPONENT, I wondered why (not so easy) in model 2. Static method implementation (in framework) is based in current thread context, maybe is not so bad? It is not "school" static access. But im not so hacker, eager to hear something

Comment: @JacekCz no, I agree. the framework designers have explicitly recommended the static access, so I guess it's the way to go. But I still think it's ugly as hell :-)

Comment: Yes, this kind of access seems to be idiomatic in Wicket. It's probably because Wicket creates a controlled environment for accessing these classes anyway. (Including built-in support for unit testing.) Personally I like to restrict its use to non-mutable configuration due to concurrency issues (Wicket guarantees single-threadedness for a lot of things but obviously not for application scope.)

Comment: Application.get() is a helper method to lookup the "current" Application, that is exported as a ThreadLocal. The application is stored in the ServletContext and exported as a ThreadLocal for each request. One can use it for many purposes, e.g. to render a special HTML attribute for each component when app.getDebugSettings() says so. But as many things in software development it could be misused.

Comment: @martin-g I know, and I have used it in the past. I still think it's a bit smelly, but it works. Personally, I'd probably manage my wicket application with spring and inject it where I need it.